# Создание UML-схем.

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, visio

Всем доброго времени суток! Слышал, что с помощью Visual Studio и Visio можно создавать UML-схемы. Как это делается? В распоряжении есть Visual Studio 2005 и Visio 2010. Хотелось бы также узнать как делать UML-схемы в Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

В VS2005 (как и во всех остальных версиях 2005-2010) выберите в контекстном меню Solution Explorer пункт "View Class Diagram". Создаётся UML-диаграмма классов, которая автоматом генерирует код на языке проекта. Свойства создаются с телом "get;set;", методы выбрасывают NotImplementedException.

Extension для VS2010:
[UML Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ce73da2a-072f-44d0-ae18-600213b56520)
(перед ним нужно будет установить еще одно расширение: Spec Explorer 2010)

А вот что Вам предлагать из эклипса даже не не знаю - уж очень большой выбор. Существуют как расширения для эклипс, так и IDE для проектирования UML на базе платформы эклипс.

Туториалы:
[Туториал для расширения Eclipse UML2 Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=432)
[Open source framework](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecemf1/)
[UML with Eclipse Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/UML/article.html)

Ссылки:
[Набор ссылок с eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2tools#uml2tools)
[eclipse4you - сайт с расширениями для эклипса](http://www.eclipse4you.com/?q=ru/taxonomy/term/27&page=1)

Обсуждение на эту тему западных коллег:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

Comment: одна проблема, для uml под visual 2010 надо ultimate edition) это уточнение)